# Copy href of a list's 2nd last element to another element on the same page

Tags: jquery, dom, copy, href

I've been trying to crack this all day with no luck. Here's my code below. I'm trying to achieve 2 things:

1. change all links with '#section-' in them to '&section='
2. change the link in the element

```
<a class="centerpadded lessonbutton standardbutton p-r-1" href="https://tsedu.gnomio.com/course/view.php?id=3">Return to Writing MCQs</a>
```

to match that of the nth-last-child(2) of the list.

```
<li class="breadcrumb-item">
    <a href="https://tsedu.gnomio.com/course/view.php?id=3#section-3">MCQ Anatomy</a>
</li>
```

I need to target the list item using the classes if possible as there are other OL elements on the page I'm editing, this is simply a small part of the code on the page I'm actually editing. I've cracked step one with the first script that appears on the page, but step 2 is eluding me.

```
<ol class="breadcrumb">
    <li class="breadcrumb-item">
        <a href="https://tsedu.gnomio.com/my/">Dashboard</a>
    </li>
    <li class="breadcrumb-item">My courses</li>
    <li class="breadcrumb-item">
        <a href="https://tsedu.gnomio.com/course/view.php?id=3" title="Writing MCQs">Writing MCQs</a>
    </li>
    <li class="breadcrumb-item">
        <a href="https://tsedu.gnomio.com/course/view.php?id=3#section-3">MCQ Anatomy</a>
    </li>
    <li class="breadcrumb-item">
        <a href="https://tsedu.gnomio.com/mod/lesson/view.php?id=50" aria-current="page" title="Lesson">Understanding MCQ Anatomy</a>
    </li>
</ol>

<div role="main">
<span id="maincontent"></span>
<h2>Understanding MCQ Anatomy
    <a class="btn btn-link p-0" role="button" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" data-content="<div class=&quot;no-overflow&quot;>
</div> " data-html="true" tabindex="0" data-trigger="focus" href="">
        <i class="icon fa fa-question-circle text-info fa-fw " title="Help with Overview" aria-label="Help with Overview" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="sr-only">Help with Overview</span>
    </a>
</h2>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs mb-3">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" title="Preview Understanding MCQ Anatomy" href="">Preview</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="https://tsedu.gnomio.com/mod/lesson/edit.php?id=50" title="Edit Understanding MCQ Anatomy">Edit</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="https://tsedu.gnomio.com/mod/lesson/report.php?id=50" title="View 0 completed attempts">Reports</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="https://tsedu.gnomio.com/mod/lesson/essay.php?id=50" title="Grade essays">Grade essays</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<h3>Congratulations - end of lesson reached</h3>
<div class="box generalbox boxaligncenter py-3">
    <p class="center">Display of grade (for students only)</p>
</div>
<p class="centerpadded">Student review only works for students.</p>
<a class="centerpadded lessonbutton standardbutton p-r-1" href="https://tsedu.gnomio.com/course/view.php?id=3">Return to Writing MCQs</a>
<a class="centerpadded lessonbutton standardbutton p-r-1" href="https://tsedu.gnomio.com/grade/index.php?id=3">View grades</a></div>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').each(function(){
        this.href = this.href.replace('#section-', '&section=');
    });
});

$('.lessonbutton').attr('href', $('ol li:nth-last-child(2)').attr('href')); 
</script>
```

Comment: `$('ol.breadcrumb li:nth-last-child(2) > a')`

Comment: You bloody legend Mohamed. I did have to be more exact in the first part as the link I wanted to change was also part of a family, but I've got the idea now from your solution. This has been bugging me for months!

Comment: Glad it helped .. Have a great day :-)